# What do you call an object that has a moon orbiting?

Tags: terminology

On Earth we call The Moon a moon, but if we were on The Moon what would we call the object we are orbiting around?

If I'm not being very clear I'm looking for a word that would describe what Earth to The Moon, Pluto to Charon, and Dactyl to Ida.

Comment: Pluto and Charon is as bad an example as Ida and Dactyl is a good one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called its [primary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_satellite). Unless it is a double planet system where there is no primary.